# "capacity exceeded, sorry[input stack size=5000]\tableofcontents"

Tags: thesis, kile

"capacity exceeded, sorry[input stack size=5000]\tableofcontents" 
I get this problem when i have added "dominitoc". Can you help me. thank you so much.

Comment: Hi and welcome. It can simply be that your file is too big. In that case you can overwrite the capacity manually. If it has to do with some logical bugs, what you should do is duplicate your file and delete irrelevant things until you can't reproduce the error message. Then you post the minimized code here so fellows can debug.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, the problem I had in the addition of "\usepackage[french]{minitoc}" with of course "\dominitoc" and "\minitoc" by to get a small table of contents for each chapter in my thesis

Comment: Some packages are just incompatible.  One would think that dominitoc would make minitoc redundant (based on the name only).